# Doctrine - SubQuery Syntax Error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this query in of my repository:

```
public function getIcoWithErrorQB()
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('iq');
    $subQuery = $this->createQueryBuilder('iqSub');
    $maxDateQuery = $this->createQueryBuilder('maxDateQuery');

    $query
        ->where(
            $query->expr()->in(
                'iq.id',
                $subQuery
                    ->select('iqSub.id')
                    ->where('iqSub.codeResponse != 0')
                    ->andWhere(
                        $subQuery->expr()->in(
                            'iqSub.lastDateRun',
                            $maxDateQuery->select('max(maxDateQuery.lastDateRun)')
                                ->groupBy('maxDateQuery.id')
                                ->getDQL()
                        )
                    )
                    ->groupBy('iqSub.order')
                    ->getDQL()
            )
        )
    ;

    return $query;
}
```

It works very well when the database have data with codeResponse <> to 0,

But when there is no codeResponse <> to 0 I have this error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 241: Error: Expected Literal, got ')'

I don't understand this error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but below code can help you

```
public function getIcoWithErrorQB()
{
    $query        = $this->createQueryBuilder('iq');
    $subQuery     = $this->createQueryBuilder('iqSub');
    $maxDateQuery = $this->createQueryBuilder('maxDateQuery');

    // Get Max value    
    $maxDateQuery->select('max(maxDateQuery.lastDateRun) as maxRun')->groupBy('maxDateQuery.id')->getQuery()->getResult();

    // SubQuery
    $subQuery->select('iqSub.id')->where('iqSub.codeResponse != 0')->groupBy('iqSub.order');
    if ($maxDateQuery) {
        $subQuery->andWhere(
            $subQuery->expr()->in(
                'iqSub.lastDateRun',
                $maxDateQuery
            )
        )
    }
    $subQueryObj = $subQuery->getQuery()->getResult();

    // Main Query
    if ($subQueryObj) {
        $query->where(
            $query->expr()->in(
                'iq.id',
                $subQueryObj
            )
        );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

**Update-1**

Replace

```
$maxDateQuery->select('max(maxDateQuery.lastDateRun) as maxRun')->groupBy('maxDateQuery.id')->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

with

```
$maxDateQuery->select('max(maxDateQuery.lastDateRun) as maxRun')->groupBy('maxDateQuery.id')->getQuery()->getResult();
```

**Update-2**

Replace

```
if (!empty($maxDateQuery['maxRun'])) {
```

with

```
if ($maxDateQuery) {
```

Please let us output of above code. So, we can fix ahead

Comment: I tried your code. I have this 500 error: `500 Internal Server Error - NonUniqueResultException`

Comment: Replace `getSingleScalarResult()` with `getResult()`. I have updated answer pls try again after updating code

Comment: Now I have this error `Cannot use object of type Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder as array
500 Internal Server Error - FatalThrowableError` on this line `if (!empty($maxDateQuery['maxRun'])) {`

Comment: Replace `(!empty($maxDateQuery['maxRun'])) {` with `if ($maxDateQuery) {`

Comment: Now I have this error: `Error: Method Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager could not be converted to string 500 Internal Server Error - FatalErrorException`